# Reactjs application build to auto run locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I hope you guys can help me, I have a reactjs application and I have built it with `npm run build` and to run it i have to run `serve -s build`.

I would like to know if there is a way to do it automatically whenever computer is turned on, and if the server goes down too, because i tried to just open `index.html` and I get an error:
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: You may want to use docker

Comment: basically you need docker!!!

Comment: oh, never heard about it, i will search for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NGINX, and serve your app content from the build folder. Example Nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen   80;

  root /home/username/path/to/build/;
  index index.html;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri =404;

}
```

Install [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/) and setup its config as described and it will create a service whenever you restart you machine it will boot up again